# image and preimage of a function - set theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I would like to know if my proof for the next argument is correct:

Let ${\displaystyle f\colon X\to Y} $ be a function, 
let ${\displaystyle G\colon P(X)\to P(Y)} $ be a function.

Suppose ${\displaystyle G[B]=F^{-1}[B] }$

so,

1. G is Surjective iff F is Injective
2. G is Injective iff F is Surjective

---

-----my final answer-----

1. ${\displaystyle \to \colon}$ suppose $G$ is surjective we will prove that $F$ is injective.

let  ${\displaystyle  a,b \in X}$ , suppose ${\displaystyle f(a)=f(b)}$ we will show that ${\displaystyle a=b}$.

${\displaystyle  a,b \in X}$  , so  ${\displaystyle {\{a}\},{\{b}\}  \subseteq X}$ so , ${\displaystyle {\{a}\},{\{b}\}  \in P(X)}$

$G$ is surjective so there exist ${\displaystyle  A,B \in P(Y)}$ so that $G(A)= {\{a}\} $ and  $G(B)= {\{b}\} $  w.l.o.g

${\displaystyle G[B]=F^{-1}[B]={\{b}\} }$ and ${\displaystyle G[A]=F^{-1}[A] ={\{a}\}}$ ,

${\displaystyle  A,B \in P(Y)}$ so ${\displaystyle  A,B \subseteq Y}$ and ${\displaystyle  f\colon X\to Y}$ , so ${\displaystyle  F^{-1}[A],F^{-1}[B] \subseteq X}$

$f$ is a function so if the preimage of $A$ and $B$ contains only one element then $A and B$ contains only one element

${\displaystyle F^{-1}[B]={\{b}\}}$ then ${\displaystyle f(b) \in B}$ so, ${\{f(b)}\} = B$

${\displaystyle F^{-1}[A]={\{a}\}}$ then ${\displaystyle f(a) \in A}$ so, ${\{f(a)}\} = A$ , $f(a)=f(b)$ so, $A=B$ so $G(A)=G(B)$ so, $a=b$

${\displaystyle \leftarrow \colon}$ suppose $F$ is injective we will prove that $G$ is surjective.

let ${\displaystyle B \in P(X)}$ we will show that there exist ${\displaystyle A\in P(Y)}$ so that $G(A)=B$.

${\displaystyle B \in P(X)}$ so ${\displaystyle B \subseteq X}$ , let $A$ be:

${\displaystyle A= {\{f(b) \in Y | b \in B }\}}$ , we can easily see that $A=Im(B)$ .

***${\displaystyle lemma \colon}$*** $f$ is injective so ${\displaystyle F^{-1}[F[B]]=B (F[B]=A})$

so ${\displaystyle F^{-1}[A]=G(A)}$ so ${\displaystyle G(A)=B}$ thus, $G$ is surjective

---

2. ${\displaystyle \rightarrow \colon}$ suppose G is Injective we need to prove that F is Surjective.

let ${\displaystyle y \in Y}$ so  ${\displaystyle {\{y}\} \subseteq Y}$  so,
${\displaystyle F^{-1}[{\{y}\}]=G({\{y}\})}$,

${\displaystyle G({\{y}\}) \in P(X)}$ so, ${\displaystyle G({\{y}\}) \subseteq X}$, so ${\displaystyle F^{-1}[{\{y}\}] \subseteq X}$

${\displaystyle F^{-1}[B]={\{x \in X| f(x) \in B}\}}$

thus, ${\displaystyle F^{-1}[∅]=∅}$ , so ${\displaystyle G(∅)=∅}$ ,  G is injective so there exist ${\displaystyle x \in G({\{y}\}}$ so, ${\displaystyle x \in F^{-1}[{\{y}\}]}$ so, ${\displaystyle f(x) \in {\{y}\}}$

only ${\displaystyle y \in {\{y}\}}$ thus, $f(x)=y$ thus, F in surjective.

${\displaystyle \leftarrow \colon}$ suppose f is surjective we will show that G is injective

let ${\displaystyle A',A \in P(Y)}$ so, ${\displaystyle A',A \subseteq Y}$, suppose $G(A')=G(A)$ , we will show that $A'=A$

${\displaystyle F^{-1}[A']=G(A')}$ and ${\displaystyle F^{-1}[A]=G(A)}$

${\displaystyle \subseteq \colon }$ let ${\displaystyle a \in A}$ , f is surjective so there is ${\displaystyle b \in X}$ so that, $f(b)=a$ so, ${\displaystyle b \in F^{-1}[A]}$ , so, ${\displaystyle b \in G(A)}$,

$G(A)=G(A')$ so,  ${\displaystyle b \in G(A')}$ so, ${\displaystyle b \in F^{-1}[A']}$ so, ${\displaystyle f(b) \in A'}$ , $f(b) = a $ , so ${\displaystyle a \in A'}$ , so ${\displaystyle A \subseteq A'}$

same for ${\displaystyle A' \subseteq A}$ , so $A'=A$ thus, G is injective.

---

---

***Lemma:*** if F is injective then ${\displaystyle F^{-1}[F[B]] = B}$  (the preimage of the image is the image)

suppose f is injective:

${\displaystyle F^{-1}[F[B]] \subseteq B \colon}$  let ${\displaystyle a \in F^{-1}[F[B]]}$ then ${\displaystyle f(a) \in [F[B]]}$ then there exist ${\displaystyle a' \in B}$ so that $f(a')=f(a)$,

$f$ is injective therefore, $a'=a$ ,so ${\displaystyle a \in B}$

${\displaystyle B \subseteq F^{-1}[F[B]] \colon}$  let ${\displaystyle a \in B}$ then ${\displaystyle f(a) \in [F[B]}$  then,  ${\displaystyle a \in F^{-1}[F[B]]}$

thus, ${\displaystyle B = F^{-1}[F[B]]}$.

---

I would like to know if the proof is correct or not, thank you:)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You are more likely to get a response if you show you have made some effort in trying to solve the problem yourself, or if you can explain where you got stuck.

Comment: This exercise is a classical one, you should be able to find answers everywhere. However, it's an interesting one, and the concepts are core in understanding surjectivity and injectivity, so I'd suggest to at least try it. It's an equivalence, so prove both assumptions by using implications (A->B then B->A to get A<->B)

Comment: sorry, ive solved most of the question ,only have one small part missing, i will edit it now with my answer so far.

Comment: Hint: $B\subseteq F^{-1}[F[B]]$ always holds, you only need injectivity for the other direction.

Comment: G[B] is confusion.   Do you mean G(A)?

Comment: @WilliamElliot where?

Comment: Assume G[B] = ... @bliblo

Comment: no, I wrote it correctly